# Como exibir apenas o primeiro nome do usuário no EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Estou fazendo um blog para treinar com node. Na aplicação, o usuário se cadastra no banco de dados e, após fazer login, vai para página dele, onde ficam todos os seus artigos. O campo no SQL vai como `name`, e eu renderizo passando para o EJS através de uma variável `user.name`.

```
<h2>Olá, <span id="trocarNome"><%-user.name%></span></h2>
```

Este código está saindo assim:

> Olá, Gustavo Henrique

Gostaria que saísse somente o primeiro nome:

> Olá, Gustavo

Gostaria de fazer com que o JavaScript usasse a função `.split(' ')`, fazendo assim ele me traz o nome até o primeiro espaço. Mas como eu faço para botar isto em prática?

Comment: Já tentou algo como ```const primeiroNome = user.name.split(' ')[0];``` e colocar esse `primeiroNome` no EJS?

Comment: deu certo, valeu!!

Answer (score 3):

Tal qual foi sinalizado no comentário, aqui está uma possível solução para o problema:

Usamos a função `split()` para obter um "array de nomes" a partir de `user.name` e selecionamos o primeiro dos "nomes" desse array com `[0]`

```js
const primeiroNome = user.name.split(' ')[0];
```

E então, no EJS, fazemos com que esse primeiro nome seja exibido dessa forma:

```
<h2>Olá, <span id="trocarNome"><%-primeiroNome%></span></h2>
```